# Using Java .jar package in asp.net 4.0 application?

Tags: java, asp.net, .net-4.0, azure, ikvm

I have a jar file exporting some functions which i want to use in my asp.net application.

How can i achieve this?

Will anything change if i use it in an windows azure application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to compile the jar into a .Net assembly and then use it in your asp.net application.

Comment: Hi todd, I found this, compiled the .jar into a .dll, but cannot use the dll, any tutorial or blog post to guide me? the post on the ikvm page isnt very helpful ...

Comment: After creating the dll, you need to add the dll as a reference to your visual studio project.  What exact errors are you encountering?

Comment: I added the reference, but couldn't access the package!

Comment: Did you add a 'using your.java.package;' statement in the source file where you want to invoke the java code?  (Or Imports in you are using VB.Net)

Comment: that was where the error was, but after I got the reason that the IKVM.OpenSDK.Core.dll was missing. Thanx for the help :) --- Also, now i wish to make a list of objects from Java as a data source for a gridview. I can't do that directly as .NET converted java code doesn't have any properties? Is there any solution apart from making proxy layer of classes which will mask the java code? shall i ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Take a look at this discussion: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.ikvm.devel/2403  I think the ikvmc -remap option might help.

Comment: Hi, Although it was sufficient for int type, what is the character to be used for String data type and complex data types? anyways i posted the question as it was deviating from the main question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687290/string-and-complex-data-types-in-map-xml-for-ikvm ...