# IKVM complex custom type error in remapping to properties!

Tags: java, .net, ikvm, remap

I used the above and wrote this:

```
<class name="umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop">
    <property name="StopName" sig="()Ljava.lang.String;">
        <getter name="getName" sig="()Ljava.lang.String;" />
        <setter name="setName" sig="(Ljava.lang.String;)Z" />
    </property>
    <property name="StopId" sig="()I">
        <getter name="getStopId" sig="()I" />
        <setter name="setStopId" sig="(I)V" />
    </property>
</class>
<class name="umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line">
    <property name="LineName" sig="()Ljava.lang.String;">
        <getter name="getName" sig="()Ljava.lang.String;" />
        <setter name="setName" sig="(Ljava.lang.String;)V" />
    </property>
    <property name="LineId" sig="()I">
        <getter name="getLineId" sig="()I" />
        <setter name="setLineId" sig="(I)V" />
    </property>
    <property name="FirstEndStop" sig="()umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;">
        <getter name="getFirstEndStop" sig="()umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;" />
        <setter name="setFirstEndStop" sig="(umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;)Z"
```

/>

/>

/>

I get an error while generating the dll file:

D:\PTS\PTS_SVN\Libraries\ikvm-0.44.0.5\bin>ikvmc -remap:map.xml -target:library
PTSDomain.jar
Note IKVMC0002: output file is "PTSDomain.dll"
Error: Invalid property signature '()umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;' in rem
ap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.FirstEndStop
Error: Invalid property getter signature '()umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;'
 in remap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.FirstEndStop
Error: Invalid property setter signature '(umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;)Z
' in remap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.FirstEndStop
Error: Invalid property signature '()umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;' in rem
ap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.SecondEndStop
Error: Invalid property getter signature '()umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;'
 in remap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.SecondEndStop
Error: Invalid property setter signature '(umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;)Z
' in remap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.SecondEndStop
Error: Invalid property signature '()[umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;' in re
map file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.Stops
Error: Invalid property getter signature '()[umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;
' in remap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.Stops
Error: Invalid property setter signature '([umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;)
Z' in remap file for property umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.Stops

D:\PTS\PTS_SVN\Libraries\ikvm-0.44.0.5\bin>

Can i use the custom properties or will i have to do that via some other way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the L in front of umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Line.Stops;

Comment: Hi, the previous issue was solved, can you please help me with the following:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131307/ikvm-java-util-list-error-in-remapping-to-properties