# IKVM java.util.List error in remapping to properties!

Tags: java, list, properties, ikvm, remap

Domain: Public Transportation System
Language: Java
Tool: IKVM

I have a class `Line` which has a list of `Stop`.

A function `getStops` returns a `List<Stop>`.
To remap the List in the class as a .NET property, what XML shall I write??

I tried the following and it did not work!

```
<property name="Stops" sig="()[Lumple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;">
    <getter name="getStops" sig="()Ljava.util.List<umple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop>;" />
    <setter name="setStops" sig="([Lumple.pts.domain.coreEntities.Stop;)Z" />
</property>
```

Also, there is another class `EmergencyLine` which has just 1 extra property: `Status`. How can inheritance be defined in IKVM, is it needed or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java VM bytecodes don't support generics (they are implemented by "erasure" by the javac compiler).

The getter signature should be the same as the property signature.

For the inheritance, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks. But, the  [ sig="()Ljava.util.List;"  ] didnt work, got an error.

Comment: The getter is deemed invalid as the java.util.List is not same as the return type, which is a generic!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I corrected the answer.